# Field Lines of a Bar Magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

I'm trying to plot magnetic field lines for a rectangular bar magnet in 3 dimensional space. The position of the magnet is known and we wish to produce a plot such as the one shown below.

Can something like the Biot Savart law be modified for an exact or approximate solution to this to enable plotting[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can model a bar magnet by a rectangular box with a constant magnetization in one direction. Let's take the box $[0,a]\times[0,b]\times[0,c]$, with a constant [magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization) $\mathbf M(\mathbf x) = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf k}$, where $\hat{\mathbf k}$ is the unit vector in the $z$ direction. The bound volume and surface current densities are:
$$\mathbf J_b(\mathbf x) = \boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf M(\mathbf x)$$
$$\mathbf K_b(\mathbf x) = \mathbf M(\mathbf x) \times \hat {\mathbf n}$$
The volume current density is zero because $\mathbf M$ is constant. For the surface current density, the top and bottom faces don't contribute since $M_0 \hat{\mathbf k}\times\hat {\mathbf k}=0$. For the other four faces we have:
$$\mathrm{x=0 \ face:} \ \mathbf K_1 = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf k}\times (-\hat{\mathbf i}) = -M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf j}$$
$$\mathrm{x=a \ face:} \ \mathbf K_2 = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf k}\times \hat{\mathbf i} = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf j}$$
$$\mathrm{y=0 \ face:} \ \mathbf K_3 = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf k}\times (-\hat{\mathbf j}) = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf i}$$
$$\mathrm{y=b \ face:} \ \mathbf K_4 = M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf k}\times \hat{\mathbf j} = -M_0 \ \hat{\mathbf i}$$
Now that you know the bound current distribution, you can simply use the Biot-Savart law to calculate the magnetic field:
$$\mathbf B(\mathbf x) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb S}d\mathbf a' \ \mathbf K(\mathbf x') \times \frac{\mathbf{x-x'}}{|\mathbf{x-x'}|^3}$$
I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks is that equations for magnetic field inside the magnet?

Comment: I gave you equations for the bound surface currents on the magnet. You can derive the magnetic fields yourself by using Biot-Savart's law and evaluating the integral (the last equation in my answer).

Comment: The spreading of the field near the ends of the bar means that is not accurate to assume a constant M. (The field at the end of a long bar is about half that at the center. Consider connecting two long magnets end to end.)

Answer (score 0):

A bar magnet is more easily represented by the equivalent electrostatic problem of plus and minus uniformly charged disks at either end of the magnet.

Comment: Modeling with two charged disks gives field lines which reverse at each disk.

Comment: The two charged disks give H which is the same as B outside the magnet.  It gives the correct H inside the magnet.  To get B inside the magnet, add 4\pi M (in Gaussian units), which is a constant vector.